# PGP Scripting with wildcards

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I am just learning PGP as this has become a critical process at my job. I am currently manually encrypting/decrypting files with PGP and I would like to script this out but I am not seeing too much documentation on that type of process.

I got the command line to encrypt the files but it puts the files with a .gpg and I need it to be .pgp.

Here is what I have tried so far.

1. gpg -e -v -r name --output c:\temp\test*.txt.pgp c:\temp\test*.txt
   This fails, but if I do gpg -e -v -r name --output c:\temp\test\test.txt.pgp c:\temp\test\test.txt, it works as designed.

The issue here is that I will have multiple files with different names but the same file extension so knowing the exact name is not going to happen until that file is created. As we are building out automation these files can range in the hundreds in the coming weeks. I am using Kleopatra and set the settings on there to pgp instead of gpg but it appears that setting does not apply to the command line.

Can anyone provide any suggestions? This is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I am not sure why I didn't think of it sooner, perhaps I was focused in the gpg commandline. Anyhow, this can be done with PowerShell.

```
    $files = Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\test"
    
    ForEach($file in $files)
    {
        gpg -e -v -r great-west --output c:\temp\test\$file.pgp c:\temp\test\$file
    }
```